# Save PNG image from Backend to Frontend to local Angular Project folder

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, png

I want to save a PNG image received from Backend (Java Project) to a folder inside my Angular Project. So far I can only save the image under Downloads/ folder of the PC and you can see how the file is downloaded. What I want is to silently download the image in my project (when I check the folder to see the new image stored).

Backend:

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("getImage")
    public Response getImage() {
        File dir = new File(Utilities.IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
        String encodedImages = null;

        // Get the first image stored in Backend project folder
        try {
            if (directoryListing != null) {
                // Encode the image in Base64 and save it in a string
                encodedImages = Base64
                                 .getEncoder()
                                 .withoutPadding()
                                 .encodeToString(
                        Files.readAllBytes(directoryListing[0].toPath()));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ...
        }

        // Send the base64 string to Frontend
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(encodedImages)
                .build();
    }
```

Frontend:

```
  /* Extract Image */
  getImage() {
    this
      .http
      .get(this.baseUrl + "getImage", { responseType: 
       'text' })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log("I received the image: \n" + res);

        // Decode from base64 to PNG
        var decodedImage = atob(res);

        var blob = new Blob([decodedImage], { type: 'image/png' });

        //this method saves the image in Downloads/ and it is not silent
        saveAs(blob, 'imageFileName.png');
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is supposed to be done in the background or user will perform the save by a click or an event?

Comment: The user clicks on a button, the Frontend sends a GET request to /baseURL + "getImage" endpoint to Backend and the Backend returns a String. With the String received I want to decode it (the string encoded is actually a PNG image). After decoding I want to save the image locally inside my project but without the user knowing that an image was downloaded. I need this to insert the image under the img that: <img src=" image.png "/>. I think I will just use <img src="data:image/png;base64,base64String"/> and I won't need to save the image locally anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since your user will not need the image it self why to download it? You don't need to download the image just for using it.
Only if your user need to download the image you could go with and "Save File" system.

Comment: I need to have the image stored in my project if I use <img src="image.png" /> (therefore to "download" it). if only I use <img src="data:image/png;base64,base64ImageString" /> then I don't need to store the image anymore

Comment: I solved the problem using the second method. Thank you for your time!